# Unable to download PDF or HTML file from Tutorial Package in R Studio

Tags: r

I am a university student using R for the first time. As part of our class, we installed a tutorial package with R (QSS Learnr - something like that), and have been tasked to complete tutorials. Once you complete a tutorial you're supposed to submit your name, press 'Download PDF', get a PDF certificate of the tutorial you just completed, and continue on your merry way. Except the programming gods have cursed me with the following error:

```
Warning: Error in : LaTeX failed to compile C:\Users\MATTHE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpq0usDx\file3618775233b6.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
  [No stack trace available]
```

I have tried:
-consulting and implementing the debugging tips from yihui.org
-I have installed TinyTex and its related packages
-I have uninstalled MiKTeX to try and solve it
-I have reinstalled MiKTeX to try and solve it

But still no dice. If anyone has any possible suggestions as to what I might be able to do, I am all ears. Otherwise, I am just going to try reinstalling R and RStudio, and pray that by starting from scratch I will somehow resolve the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output from these two commands? `install.packages('tinytex')` and `tinytex::install_tinytex()`

Comment: > install.packages('tinytex')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Matthew Erskine/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/tinytex_0.28.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 116500 bytes (113 KB)
downloaded 113 KB

package ‘tinytex’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\Matthew Erskine\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSuHoEs\downloaded_packages

Comment: `> tinytex::install_tinytex()
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 102958647 bytes (98.2 MB)
downloaded 98.2 MB

Warning: conflicting [pdf]tex program found on the system path in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\; not fixable in user mode.` blahblahblah
`tlmgr.pl: package log updated: C:/Users/Matthew Erskine/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log`